# How to upload a file using laravel that will use the exact file name on my public folder and at my database

Tags: laravel

I have been searching a few codes but didnt manage to work.
The one I found is using jscon encode.
Is there any way to upload a file without changing its name into storage and database?

```
        $fileModal = new Image();
    $fileModal->name = json_encode($imgData);
    $fileModal->image_path = json_encode($imgData);
    
   
    $fileModal->save();
```

I didnt understand the json part. Was hoping to use a built in laravel.
I used the one in the documentation but didnt help.

```
          $path = $request->file('namefile')->storeAs(
          'DocumenSokongan', $request->user()->id
        );
```

Comment: when you upload a file, php will save the file in a temp directory in a temporary name, you have to move and rename the file to where you want. But you can get the original name back as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$image = $request->file('filename');
$imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();   
$image->move($path, $imageName);
```